# obj-c app is not localized programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to change the language programmatically through the extension of `NSBundle` -- `NSBundle setLanguage: (NSString *) language`. I have several application localizations.

Some localizations work correctly, but when installing Spanish and Italian languages, instead of localized strings, I see the names of the `localizable.strings` parameters. The same happens with some other languages, but not with all the lines.

Tell me please what can be the problem

UPD:

here is some of the lines in English:

```
"CLOSE_TITLE"         = "Close";
"PAYMENT_TITLE"       = "Pay";
"PAYMENT_TITLE_IN"    = "Deposit";
```

and they are also in Spanish:

```
"CLOSE_TITLE" = "Cerrar";
"PAYMENT_TITLE" = "Retirar";
"PAYMENT_TITLE_IN" = "Depositar";
```

There is code of extension:

```
#import "NSBundle+Language.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static const char _bundle=0;

@interface BundleEx : NSBundle
@end

@implementation BundleEx
-(NSString*)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName
{
    NSBundle* bundle=objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_bundle);
    return bundle ? [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName] : [super localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName];
}
@end

@implementation NSBundle (Language)


+(void)setLanguage:(NSString*)language
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
                  {
                      object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle],[BundleEx class]);
                  });
    objc_setAssociatedObject([NSBundle mainBundle], &_bundle, language ? [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]] : nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}


@end
```

Comment: can you show some strings which are in english and as well as in other languages ? so we can check that code

Comment: Not Clear, I think you should share some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the code had a non-printable space character `&nbsp;` so part of the parameters after this character is not translated. XСode does not display this character. This can happen if you translate through web services. When I removed this symbol in all localizations, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

How are you dragging the new localization files to the project? I found out that when you add new languages to xCode, it's best to first remove the whole folder from xCode completely and then drag everything including the new languages back all at the same time :)

Comment: I added files one by one ... ok, I'll try